# How to create proper autogenerated code in C# for gRPC?

Tags: c#, grpc, proto, grpc-c#

I created a proto file in a C# Project and tried to auto-generate C# codes by building the solution.
But, I have an issue with the file under the extension grpc.cs.

```
''' 

/// <summary>Creates a new client for Greeter</summary>
   /// <param name="channel">The channel to use to make remote calls.</param>
      public GreeterClient(grpc::Channel channel) : base(channel)
      {
      }

'''
```

The above snip is from the example, where the public GreeterClient has the parameter (grpc::Channel channel)
But in the below snip, it's (grpc::ChannelBase channel)

```
'''

/// <summary>Creates a new client for samples</summary>
/// <param name="channel">The channel to use to make remote calls.</param>
public samplesClient(grpc::ChannelBase channel) : base(channel)
{
}

'''
```

This throws an error telling **'Client Channel can't be found**

How to **configure** and **generate the grpc.cs file** so that the **parameter is (grpc::Channel channel)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what are you doing (...tried to autogenerate... <- you mean you running protoc manually ? Why ?)

This is an example for .NET Framework project, .NET Core created slight different - here is excelent resource to get started for .NET Core: [ASP.NET Core gRPC for WCF Developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/)

Usually what you do

1. Create project and install relevant Nuget packages: `Grpc`, `Grpc.Core` and most importantly the `Grpc.Tools` package
2. Add new file. Name it whetever you want but extension must be `.proto`
3. Fill some data inside this proto file like:

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "MyNamespace";

...
...
```

4. Right mouse click on this file and select `Properties`
5. In the 'Properties' panel select `Protobuf` as a `Build action`. So it should look like this:

[image]

6. Rebuild the solution
7. Add another C# file, name it anything you want
8. In this C# file start referencing the structures you created in `proto` file. Like:

`MyNamespace.MyServer server = new MyNamespace.MyServer()`

but actually you should inherit from base class that `ptotobuf` created for you like this:

```
 public class GrpcImplementationClass: MyNamespace.MyServer.MyServerBase
 {

   public override MyFunction()
   {
   ...
   ...
```

P.S. There's a lot of tutorials for beginnners on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=grpc+c%23)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed procedure.
Are steps 7 and 8 mandatory?

Comment: @Sree: What we doing here - is creating C# project that use gRPC technology to communicate with something.So until step 6 we created gRPC configuration and make sure that C# tools can work/generate with it but what it good for if we does not actually use it in our C# application ? So in step 6 and 7 we actually startign to build our C# app with our own logic and needs that will use gRPC technology to communicate with remote server

Comment: Thank you so much. This explains the steps.